# Where exactly in the proof is the boundedness of $\sigma(x)$ and $b(x)$ being used?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I was reading the proof of pathwise uniqueness in the book of Ikeda and Watanabe but I am not sure where is the boundedness of $\sigma(x)$ and $b(x)$ being used? I am attaching the proof below and I think the boundedness is being used at the place **marked in red** since boundedness ensures thatthe stochastic integral and the integral in red are well defined. Am I correct or is it being used somewhere else?
[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would like to point out that in Yamada, Watanabe's original paper where they proved this theorem, boundedness of $\sigma$ and $b$ was not used. See https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250523691

Comment: Also, there are plenty of SDEs with unbounded $\sigma$ and $b$ with pathwise unique solutions. In particular, this is the case whenever $\sigma$, $b$ are Lipschitz and $O(|x|)$.

Comment: Actually I am aware of the fact that this holds when the coefficients aren’t bounded but are just continuous / holder continuous with coefficient 1/2, but that is proved with stopping arguments .

Comment: Well, what I meant to say was that I think the boundedness requirement is a mistake.

Comment: But in this particular case they indeed assume boundedness and it’s not particularly clear to me where exactly it is being used. Indeed we need sigma and b to satisfy some regularity conditions for the integrals to be well defined and that is exactly why we use the stopping arguments in the case when they aren’t bounded . But I am not sure if it is being used somewhere else as well ! Any ideas ?

Comment: I read the proof from Yamada, Watanbe's paper (both proofs are essentially same) and it seemed fine without any boundedness condition. Also, I don't think you need boundedness to guarantee the existence of the stochastic integrals.

Comment: Even if we consider the Lebesgue integral without some kind of boundedness or stopping the integral $\int_0^t b(X(t)$ is not well defined

Comment: For example the solution could explode in finite time